# Swift: import framework but can't find class in it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I import a swift framework to a swift project, but when I call the class in this framework, Xcode  throw a compile error "Use of undeclared type 'xxxx(class name)' ".

I feel Xcode have found the framework, otherwise it will complaint "can't find xxx(framework name)".

But why Xcode can't find the class of this framework.

I have tried remove and re-add framework, and delete DeivedData files, but all of them not work. I haven't use CocoaPods to import framework.

Any idea?

Comment: Which framework you are using ?

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuild and after using class name if still it shows you error just try writing code related to that file in DidLoad just try

Comment: try to delete import and use that class. It works or not? sometimes we don't need to import as well.

Comment: this framework is provide by our customer. and I know the root case now, it is the framework's issue,  this framework only provide the real device, not provide simulator, thanks all.

Answer (score 16):

In a Framework that was built for Release (and not Debug), the class symbols need to be accessible.

Make sure you are you trying to access Public or Open classes from your Swift framework.

```
// set the Framework class to Public
public class rnHello{  

    // set the initializer to public, otherwise you cannot invoke class
    public init() {  

    }

    // set the function to public, as it defaults to internal
    public static func world() {  
        print("hello from a static method")
    }
}
```

Now you can access this via your Swift code or if you attach lldb using:

`lldb) po rnHello.world()`

Comment: Worker for me on an a SPM package

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the FrameWorkSearch path in the BuildSettings of the project is reflecting the correct path to your framework.