# Swift: import framework but can't find class in a workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, project, workspace

Similar to '[Swift: import framework but can't find class in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939490/swift-import-framework-but-cant-find-class-in-it)' but different.

I have a Xcode workspace using CocoaPods for some libs. I did create my own framework and drop it to the workspace like I did for a Xcode project. In both the import statement finds the framework but in the workspace the classes are not found. The Xcode project does not have any problems.

If I open the project instead of the workspace Xcode will find the classes in the framework.

Whats might be wrong?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the project, but the most probable case is that you haven't marked your classes in the framework as `public`

Comment: I think in this case I would also not find the classes if I open the project and not the workspace. I did already try to create a second framework with only one class and this one is public. Same behavior.

Comment: So, without seeing your code it is hard to help you. Post your project or example project with your framework on github - and you will get help

Comment: Thanks for help. While waiting for an inspiration I decide to try a different way after nothing works what I found here before I post my question. I did add the project to my workspace and finally the framework to the 'Embedded Binaries'. That works finally for me. Looks like a path was missing.

Answer (score 1):

My package would not see some objects without any hint of why not. The tests in the package worked and the SwiftUI previews worked in the imported packages.

It turned out that my package contained both extensions and classes that had not been marked public and they could not be seen in the imported package.
I marked the extensions with the public keyword and marked both the classes and their init() with the public keyword.

I found this comment above, which solved my issue:
"Hard to say without seeing the project, but the most probable case is that you haven't marked your classes in the framework as public – lobstah" Thanks lobstah!